# If the probability of an event is $0$ , does it mean that the event is empty?

Tags: probability, statistics

If the probability of an event is $0$, does it mean that the event is empty?

Comment: If $X$ is a continuous random variable (e.g., pick a number between $0$ and $1$ uniformly), then the probability of getting any particular value of $X$ (e.g. $X=0.5$) is zero, even though it is possible for the event to occur.

Comment: But why is the probability of getting any particular value 0 ?

Comment: Because there are infinitely many real numbers within any interval [a,b] with a < b. So the probability of choosing a single number is 0.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, no. For example if we define $\Pr([a,b])=b-a$, where $[a,b]\subset [0,1]$, then even though $\{0.5\}=[0.5,0.5]$ is not empty, the probability is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not even true on a discrete sample space. Consider $\Omega=\{1,2\}$ and define $p(\{1\})=0$ and $p(\{2\})=1$. Then $p(\{1\})=0$ but $\{1\}$ is nonempty.

Answer (score 1):

Think of tossing a fair coin. You can make the sample space as $\{head, tail, edge\}$. And the probabilities are:
$$P(H)=P(T)=0.5, P(E)=0.$$